# MATLAB: How can I properly work with index values in a meshgrid?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, mesh

Let's say I have two vectors ( Elem and Dren ). Each row in Dren represents a sum of a possible combination of elements from Elem . ID is an array that has the same number of rows as Dren and stores the indexes of Elem that correspond to every row in Dren .

Example:

```
Elem = [3 2 6];
Dren = [3; 2; 6; 5; 9; 8; 11];
ID = [  1     0     0;
    2     0     0;
    3     0     0;
    1     2     0;
    1     3     0;
    2     3     0;
    1     2     3];
```

Then I used a meshgrid for Elem and Dren to get all possible pairs of these values and created a new array ( R ) with their ratios, as shown below:

```
[E,D]=meshgrid(Elem,Dren);
for line=1:size(E,1)
   for col=1:size(E,2)
      R(line,col)=D(line,col)./E(line,col);
   end
end
```

This gives me:

```
R =
1.0000e+000  1.5000e+000  5.0000e-001
6.6667e-001  1.0000e+000  3.3333e-001
2.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  1.0000e+000
1.6667e+000  2.5000e+000  8.3333e-001
3.0000e+000  4.5000e+000  1.5000e+000
2.6667e+000  4.0000e+000  1.3333e+000
3.6667e+000  5.5000e+000  1.8333e+000
```

I have filtered the results of R and selected the ones that are lower than 6, so I get:

```
R6 = R(find(R<6))

R6 =
1.0000e+000
6.6667e-001
2.0000e+000
1.6667e+000
3.0000e+000
2.6667e+000
3.6667e+000
1.5000e+000
1.0000e+000
3.0000e+000
2.5000e+000
4.5000e+000
4.0000e+000
5.5000e+000
5.0000e-001
3.3333e-001
1.0000e+000
8.3333e-001
1.5000e+000
1.3333e+000
1.8333e+000
```

Now I would like to create a new array that will store these filtered values in the first column and show the row values from ID equivalent to them. In other words, the first column would be R(find(R<6) and the other columns would be the Elem indexes related to the Dren value used in every R calculation. Since I used the find function in R, I don't know how to associate the correct ID rows.

For example, for R6(1,1)= 1.0000e+000, we know it was calculated from D(1,1)=3, so the corresponding ID row is [ 1     0     0]. The first row of the array would therefore be:

```
Store(1,:) = [ 1.0000e+000 1     0     0 ]
```

How can I do this for all the elements in R6?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @HelP - awww.... I just solved it for you :(.  Can you check to see if my solution is right anyway?

Comment: @HelP - Aha! My pleasure dude :).  I am glad that you figured it out on your own though.  Those are the best triumphs.  Thank you for accepting my answer regardless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very easy to solve.  What you should do is use the **two** output version of `find`.

```
[row_R6, col_R6] = find(R<6);
```

`row_R6` will store the row locations and `col_R6` will store the column locations of those values in `R` whose values are `< 6`.  You can then use `row_R6` to index your ID matrix to grab the right rows.  As such:

```
format long
Store = [R6 ID(row_R6,:)] %// R6 created a priori
```

We thus get:

```
Store =

1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000                   0                   0
0.666670000000000   2.000000000000000                   0                   0
2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0                   0
1.666700000000000   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000                   0
3.000000000000000   1.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0
2.666700000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0
3.666700000000000   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000
1.500000000000000   1.000000000000000                   0                   0
1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000                   0                   0
3.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0                   0
2.500000000000000   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000                   0
4.500000000000000   1.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0
4.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0
5.500000000000000   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000
0.500000000000000   1.000000000000000                   0                   0
0.333330000000000   2.000000000000000                   0                   0
1.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0                   0
0.833330000000000   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000                   0
1.500000000000000   1.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0
1.333300000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000                   0
1.833300000000000   1.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.000000000000000
```